# Which linux kernel architecture am I using

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, archlinux

In the kernel code, there are a lot of Makefile(s) that use macro to define which driver is used or not (example : CONFIG_USB_NET_SMSC95XX in https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/204050d0eafb565b68abf512710036c10ef1bd23/drivers/net/usb/Makefile). The value of such variables is defined in the /arch/..... repository. I would like to find which architecture I am using (my linux has been built from) and how this architecture is chosen.

I also find it disturbing that sometimes, this value is m (which means that the driver is loaded as a module) and sometimes it is y (which means taht it is not removable).

If you know any documentation about this, that would also be awesome.

Thank you!

Comment: It depends upon the compilation steps which you followed. By default it is for X86_64 but you can set it through ARCH=<arch_name> like ARCH=arm. Apart from this you should also know the defconfig file for your processor which eventually set the final configuration(.config) for your kernel. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392756/what-does-m-mean-in-kernel-configuration-file

Answer (score 0):

uname comand provides you that info . Type $uname --help to see or just

```
$ uname -v
```

to show the kernel version

Comment: Thank you for the information, do you know how it is chosen among all arch available?

Comment: I just tried to answer the title question. I am not a kernel-compiling specialist but, as far as I'm concerned, this is defined in compiling time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by Using `screenfetch` command

```
sudo pacman -Syu   
pacman -S screenfetch
```

This will show you bunch on information you need to know 
simply type `screenfetch` on Terminal